# Hibernate deleted child stays in parent list

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to delete a child without having to through it through the parent (one-to-many). I know it usually goes like:

```
Parent p = db.getParent(parentId);
p.getChildList().remove(child);
db.update(p);
```

Do I have to do something to allow this?

```
db.delete(child);
```

When I do this and retrieve the parent again, it has a null value in its list of children. Can I do something to the xml mapping file to have it completely removed?

Parent

```
    <list name="child" inverse="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <key column="PARENTID" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="childOrder"/>
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </list>
```

Child

```
    <property name="parentId" type="string" update="false" insert="false">
        <column name="PARENTID" not-null="false">
        </column>
    </property>
    <property name="childOrder" type="java.lang.Integer" update="false" insert="false">
        <column name="CHILDORDER" not-null="false">
        </column>
    </property>
```

Comment: Provide more information about how the Parent and Child are mapped.

Comment: @ShankarPS Hi Shankar, I edited to show the mapping. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have still given just a pseudo code. Please always post questions with actual code, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a typo in your question, but why are you removing the childId? You should use the child object.

Try this, if not already done.

```
//Look up the child object and then use it.
Child c = (Child) session.get(Child.class, new Integer(childId));
p.getChildList().remove(child);         
session.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

Comment: Sorry, child was what I meant. Hibernate sessions are hidden to us and we just use an interface they provide although we provide the mapping (hence childId vs child). If my Child object does not have a reference to the parent, is this an uni-directional relationship? Meaning only the parent has a link to the child but the child doesn't have a link to the parent? If so, is this why in my case, deleting the child doesn't remove it from the parent's list?

Comment: Yes. It is a unidirectional relationship, if the Child does not refer the Parent. But you have specified "inverse=false", which means that the Parent owns the relationship. So, this should work. But I noticed that you ahve set update="false" and insert="false". Why is that? They mean that this column will nver be changed. Can you remove that and try?

Comment: Sorry Shankar, turns out I missed a line of mapping. There is also a childOrder (updated in mapping) that we want the parent to keep charge of. Everytime a child is added, its order value is set. Why would an update+insert false cause the problem I'm seeing? Thanks a lot.